# Equal horizontal space between links in responsive navigation?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I am trying to make horizontal menu navigation. I have several links in navigation, and I would like to have equal horizontal space between them.

How to make links in horizontal menu with equal space between them?

HTML:

```
    <div id="header">
    <div class="secondary-navigation">
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
            <nav id="navigation">
            <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             <li class="menu-item"><a href="" title="Link" itemprop="url">Link</a></li>
             </ul>
             <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
             </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------
/* Header navigation
/*---------------------------------------------*/
.secondary-navigation {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.secondary-navigation a {
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #F1F1F1;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333888;
}

.secondary-navigation a:hover, .secondary-navigation .sfHover {
     color: #F1F1F1;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #F1F1F1;
      }
.secondary-navigation li li a { line-height: 1 }
.secondary-navigation a .sub {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #CFCFCF;
    text-transform: none;
}
.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    content: "▼";
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #F1F1F1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: 22px;
}
.footer-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a:after { display: none }
.sub-menu .menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    right: 0;
    top: 17px;
}
.menu .current-menu-item > a { background: #fff }
.menu .current-menu-item > a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#navigation ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;  /*Added*/}
#navigation .menu { float: left; }
#navigation ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#navigation > ul li:first-child a {  }
#navigation > ul li:last-child a { border-right: 0 }
#navigation ul .header-search { float: right }
#navigation > ul > li:last-child { border-right: none }
#navigation ul li a, #navigation ul li a:link, #navigation ul li a:visited { display: block }
#navigation > ul > .current a {
    background: transparent;
    color: #555 !important;
}
#navigation li:hover ul, #navigation li li:hover ul, #navigation li li li:hover ul, #navigation li li li li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    left: -228px;
    top: 0;
}
#navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    z-index: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333888;
    border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul ul li {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 10%;
    width: 80%;
    color: #333;
}
#navigation ul ul li:hover { background: #F1F1F1 }
#navigation ul ul a, #navigation ul ul a:link, #navigation ul ul a:visited {
    padding: 12px 0;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#navigation ul ul li:last-child a { border-bottom: none }
#navigation ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -999em;
}
#navigation ul li:hover ul {
    left: -1px;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 81px;
}
#navigation ul ul li:hover ul {
    top: -1px;
    left: -228px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#navigation ul ul ul:after { border-color: transparent }
```

I tried something like [this](http://codepen.io/bigmantonyd/pen/ZYGoop), but it does not work for me.

Comment: Can you use flexbox? This would be a perfect opportunity for its use.

Comment: I am not familiar with that. I didn't try that. Is it widely supported?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-box - you'll need to add vendor prefixes in most cases

Comment: This is a good resource for getting started with flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `justify-content: space-between` or `justify-content: space-around` **flexbox** property

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Random Link</li>
  <li>Random Link</li>
  <li>Random Link</li>
  <li>Random Link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please incorporate it into my CSS, I have trouble with it?

Comment: While this answer technically correct, make sure you read up on flexbox, the prefixes, etc, that come with it. There are also more properties that should be added then what Nenad has posted. Such as the flex values for the `<li>` elements.